# Google Cloud Endpoints: How to identify the client type?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Within the endpoints handler method, how can the client information be obtained.

Whether the request came from Webclient or Android or iOS?

Also, how to identify whether the request came from API Explorer?

Comment: If I understand well your first question, you can get the current user by invoking endpoints.get_current_user(), see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/endpoints/auth

Comment: @3371862 Thanks. I am not looking for the user, but how the user tried accessing the API. Whether through browser/javascript (if possible which browser), Android App or iOS App?

Comment: Ok! For your last question, have a look at point #1 in http://stackoverflow.com/a/42521425/3371862

Answer (score 0):

The `User-Agent` header identifies most official clients by language. It will contain something similar to `google-http-java-client` or `google-api-java-client`. For JavaScript, you should look at `X-Javascript-User-Agent`.